# How to use certain node module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

My goal is to read in graphml files and retreive information about the fields that are contained within the nodes.

I have found [a node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphml-schema-generator) that seems to do just that so I decided I'd give it a try before writing my own code.

Unfortunately I the documentation is pretty poor and I have only been using node.js for about three months so I cannot figure out what the few clues given mean.

> **Global Install**
>   npm install -g graphml-schema-generator
>   To have the wizard assist you with questions, type: gschema And answer the questions until finished.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the following syntax: **gschema path/to/graphml/file path/to/out/directory** The paths can be either relative or absolute. The tool should pick on it either way.
>
> **Local Install**
>   npm install --save graphm-schema-generator
>   You can either type the whole path to the file each time, such as: ./node_modules/gml-to-typescript/build/index Or you can create an npm script that references the path
>
> However you choose to go about it, the usage is exactly the same as stated in the Global Install section. Please refer to that.
>
> If you don't want to pollute your development environment this might be a better way to install this. Then you can use npm scripts to alias it to a more manageable command.

There's no GitHub repository or what-so-ever. I have read through the code and basically there are three files of which two seem to be sourcefiles (exporting some modules that are used in the last one) and one that's called "app.ts".

I somehow expected that I could use this module like

```
import {<ModuleName>} from 'graphml-schema-generator';
```

or

```
require('./node_modules/graphml-schema-generator";
```

but this isn't the case. I do not understand what

```
gschema path/to/graphml/file path/to/out/directory
```

would mean or how it would be used. I guess there's some basic misunderstanding about packages on my side.

[here's an Image of the modules hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gc9j.png)

So I want to understand how to use this module and if so, what I did wrong
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad
When I try to use import or require it cannot find the module until I specifically enter the path to each file. Moreover, it seems like you don't create an instance of an exported module. The App.js file uses, for instance, "process.argv" which is used to capture input from the terminal (I guess) which leads me to thinking that I have to use this module via terminal and I don't know how to do this. The instructions on the node modules page aren't clear enough to me.